# How to output a value from a post meta which contains multiple arrayed post meta keys - values

Tags: php, arrays

I have a custom field fw_options which looks like below. I am trying to extract data such as gender, _books_read, other_skills (especially this) etc but I can't get my head around this type of custom field. I know how to output a custom field using `get_post_meta( get_the_ID()`, I just don't know how to extract data from this kind of format. I am a complete beginner in PHP but I'm really trying to understand.

My Code
`<span>$ <?php echo get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'fw_options', true ); ?></span>`

Post Meta Key - fw_options
Value (below)

```
  0 => 
  array (
    'gender' => 'male',
    'tag_line' => 'I like reading journals and thriller books,',
    '_books_read' => 12,
    'address' => '',
    'longitude' => '',
    'latitude' => '',
    'country' => 
    array (
      0 => 720,
    ),
    'other_skills' => 
    array (
      0 => 
      array (
        'other_skill' => 
        array (
          0 => '833',
        ),
        'value' => '80',
      ),
      1 => 
      array (
        'other_skill' => 
        array (
          0 => '507',
        ),
        'value' => '99',
      ),
      2 => 
      array (
        'other_skill' => 
        array (
          0 => '1169',
        ),
        'value' => '99',
      ),
    ),
    'current_books' => 
    array (
    ),
    'awards' => 
    array (
    ),
    'experience_level' => 
    array (
    ),
    'education_level' => 
    array (
    ),
    'banner_image' => 
    array (
    ),
    'resume' => 
    array (
    ),
    'tutorials' => 
    array (
    ),
    'english_level' => 'fluent',
    'reader_type' => 'medium',
  ),
)
```

Comment: You basically just go through the keys names in order to get their values. To get gender, it would be `$array[0]['gender']` should give you `male`. To get other skills, you would do `$array[0]['other_skills'][0]['other_skill'][0]` should give you `833`. `$array[0]['other_skills'][0]['value']` should give you `80` etc...

Comment: hi, thanks for the suggestion. I used it like this `<?php echo get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), '$array[0]['other_skills'][0]['other_skill'][0]', true ); ?>` but it did not work. Is this how I should do it in my code?

Comment: No, what you have in your code is an array, so it's a big set of data. You don't echo the whole array out, you have to assign the array to a variable and access the array keys from the variable. So something like `$array = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'fw_options', true ); echo $array[0]['other_skills'][0]['other_skill'][0];`

Comment: Worked like charm!

Comment: I would follow this example given in the PHP manual regarding multidimensional array, it is a clear representation of how to access values in such an array: https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php#example-62